# How AWS DMS full load migration affect source database performance?

Tags: mysql, database-migration, amazon-aurora, aws-dms

Do you know how an AWS DMS full load from a MySQL Aurora as a source database affects its performances?

My cluster MySQL Aurora is used in production and cannot have any downtime or bad performance.

I ve difficulties finding any clue on AWS documentation.

Comment: Why do you need a "DMS full load"?

Comment: I need a first sync to reach the same state, then I might need to restart the connector if the states of the linked databases diverges.